# Scale window contents appropriately to each display

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a couple monitors with different resolutions. I have them each set to use their maximal resolution, using Displays. This works great.

I have set scaling on the high-dpi display to 2.0, so things are easier to see.

Also in Displays, there is an drop-down called 'Scale all window contents to match': 'Display with largest controls', 'Display with smallest controls', ....

Setting one of these options means that the text on one display is the right size, and the text on the other display is too big. If I set it the other way, one's the right size and the other's too small.

Ideally, I would have each window be scaled appropriately to the display that it's on. Is it possible to get windows scaled appropriately across different displays?

Comment: Not sure it it's possible to scale window per display. How about setting each display to different resolution ? does that help ?

Comment: had an idea:  i could write a script where scaling switches depending on which display is the currently active window is. Not ideal solution but at least it automates what youndo manually

Comment: This is another one of the many many many (yes, 3 "many"s) issues that makes Linux a pain, despite the fact I use it every day and love certain aspects of it. Come on Ubuntu! Fix it! :) What a stupid behavior. I'm fighting with it too. My extra monitor is huge and 4x the resolution of my laptop monitor. This  "feature" (bug) makes the laptop monitor display things so huge it's almost not worth using.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much not not not (yes: 3 "nots" bad) ideal, but it's the best I can come up with, as I have the same problem as you.

Just individually zoom each program depending on which monitor it is running on to get a size that's more reasonable.

Ex: in LibreOffice use the zoom buttons in the bottom right.

In the terminal use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>)</kbd> to reset the zoom.

In Google Chrome use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>)</kbd> to reset the zoom.

You get the idea.

This is NOT a great solution. It DOES require re-adjusting the zoom each time you drag a window from one monitor to another, and it IS a pain-in-the-butt.

Shame on you Ubuntu! :)